# For Python code: Does Mac OS X contain an X terminal? (If not, which?)

Tags: macos, terminal

I can't seem to find an answer on google.  Can anyone please check if `xterm` is installed on Mac OS X by default, or better yet, if the program/link `x-terminal-emulator` is defined?

The reason I am asking is that I am currently running this python3 code

```
process = subprocess.Popen ( ['x-terminal-emulator', '-e',  'sh -c "cd"' ]  )
```

(for simplicity, more complicated bash command replaced with `cd`) and would prefer compatibility with mac.  If anyone could also check that this runs gracefully (it should just briefly pop up a new terminal), I'd be obliged.

Otherwise, which terminal should I call for that specific command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11 for Mac OS X is installed by default, but it's optional, so you cannot be sure xterm is installed, see http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/x11.html

What is always there on a Mac OS X box is the Terminal.app

Answer (score 1):

That works, at least on Lion, if you call `'xterm'` specifically (there is no `x-terminal-emulator` link).